# Can't install Win 8.1 to my new Dell I5 computer

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, windows-8.1, windows-installation, gpt

i just got a new dell I5 computer with on Operating system inside, i tried to install win 8.1 as the manual said but when i got to the Hard drive i got the message "windows cannot be installed on this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style."

I really need help on what steps to take in installing the OS.

Thanks

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=DQf9YqbD8WI

Comment: Open the bootmneu in your pc and make sure you select UEFI boot of your DVD

Answer (score 0):

This might help: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/windows-cannot-be-installed-on-this-disk-the/8fa72a3e-10c5-47da-a040-1e0db62af309
It applies to Windows 7 specifically, but probably applies to 8.1 as well.